# xcodebuild + iPhone fail under ssh with Couldn't load plug-in 'com.apple.Xcode.iPhoneSupport'

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, xcodebuild

I'm triying to compile my iPhone app from ssh. This is for my build tool that run in another machine.

The base sdk is iPhone Device 3.0.

The error is : "Couldn't load plug-in 'com.apple.Xcode.iPhoneSupport'"

However, executing from the regular terminal run ok. Also directly from xcode.

This is the log:

```
[trtrrtrtr@mac-pro-de-trtrr-trtr ~/mamcx/projects/JhonSell/iPhone]$ xcodebuild -target BestSeller -configuration Debug=== BUILDING NATIVE TARGET Three20 OF PROJECT Three20 WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Checking Dependencies...
No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=armv6, VALID_ARCHS=i386).
2010-04-27 16:16:50.369 xcodebuild[1168:4b1b] Error loading /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/iPhoneRemoteDevice.xcodeplugin/Contents/MacOS/iPhoneRemoteDevice:  dlopen(/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/iPhoneRemoteDevice.xcodeplugin/Contents/MacOS/iPhoneRemoteDevice, 265): no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/iPhoneRemoteDevice.xcodeplugin/Contents/MacOS/iPhoneRemoteDevice: GC capability mismatch
2010-04-27 16:16:50.371 xcodebuild[1168:4b1b] Exception caught: Couldn't load plug-in 'com.apple.Xcode.iPhoneSupport'
2010-04-27 16:16:50.373 xcodebuild[1168:4b1b] Error loading /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/iPhoneRemoteDevice.xcodeplugin/Contents/MacOS/iPhoneRemoteDevice:  dlopen(/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/iPhoneRemoteDevice.xcodeplugin/Contents/MacOS/iPhoneRemoteDevice, 265): no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/iPhoneRemoteDevice.xcodeplugin/Contents/MacOS/iPhoneRemoteDevice: GC capability mismatch
2010-04-27 16:16:50.373 xcodebuild[1168:4b1b] Exception caught: Couldn't load plug-in 'com.apple.Xcode.iPhoneSupport'
** BUILD FAILED **
```

Answer (score 0):

If it runs fine under Xcode and terminal on the same machine then it is probably a permissions problem with the user in ssh.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem in the XCode project. See the following line:

```
No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=armv6, VALID_ARCHS=i386).
```

It indicates that:

- You enabled the "Build Active Architecture Only" checkbox in the "BestSeller" target.
- You only have "armv6" as active architecture, whereas the only valid architectures are "i386".

I suggest you to check that these options are correctly defined under XCode. Then, you can go these ways:

- perform a build under the XCode GUI.
- perform a build on the command line.
- on the local machine, use ssh to connect and perform a build on the command line.
- on the remote machine, use ssh to connect and perform a build on the command line.

For each attempt, save the output and compare them. Maybe the architecture problem is not the only one, but by doing it by steps it will be easier to spot the problem.